# Mantain only first instance of each duplicated values in array

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the following populated array:

```
[
  1 => 21
  2 => 19
  3 => 19
  4 => 19
  5 => 18
  6 => 18
  7 => 16
  8 => 15
  9 => 15
  10 => 15
  11 => 15
  12 => 14
  13 => 14
  14 => 14
  15 => 13
  16 => 13
  17 => 12
  18 => 11
  19 => 11
  20 => 11
  21 => 11
  22 => 11
  23 => 9
  24 => 9
  25 => 8
]
```

I am trying to iterate this array and mantain **only one** and **the first** instance of each duplicated value, **as well as the key**, such as I can have the following output:

```
[
  2 => 19
  5 => 18
  8 => 15
  12 => 14
  15 => 13
  18 => 11
  23 => 9
]
```

So far, I'm only being able to mantain an **erratic** instance of each duplicated value, resulting in this output:

```
[
  3 => 19
  6 => 18
  9 => 15
  13 => 14
  16 => 13
  19 => 11
  24 => 9
]
```

This output I'm receiving using the following code:

```
$arrayFiltered = array_unique(array_diff_assoc($array, array_unique($array)));
```

Comment: What are you taking in consideration to filter this array?

Comment: @j08691 I have found many solutions for plain arrays, but not for dimensional arrays.

Comment: You need to make an effort and post it in your question. A loop or array_map would seem like a logical place to start.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, I apologize, I tried 10 different things.

Comment: You need to post the code you are using and also the expected output after the code has run. We have no idea what you expect the result to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

Based off your updates, I've got this for you. It's essentially only returning the value to the `$new` array if it's count is more than 1 (duplicate) within the `$array`. That's where [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) comes in. It'll clean up everything else and only show you the very first instance of each duplicate, as you require.

```
$new = array_unique(array_filter($array, function(&$item) use($array){

    if(count(array_keys($array, $item)) > 1) {
        return $item;
    }

}));
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#o8D3BCz4v)

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 19
    [5] => 18
    [8] => 15
    [12] => 14
    [15] => 13
    [18] => 11
    [23] => 9
)
```

---

Comment: Ok, but this will give me back values such as 21, 16, 12 and 8, which are not duplicated. I don't need those.

Comment: @user2094178 I've updated my answer with what you need to get the desired values.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is really nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `foreach()`, `array_count_values()`, and `array_search()` like so:

```
$new    =   array();
$multi  =   array_count_values($arr);
foreach($multi as $key => $value) {
        if($value <= 1)
            continue;
        $search         =   array_search($key,$arr);
        $new[$search]   =   $arr[$search];
    }

print_r($new);
```

**Gives you:**

```
(
    [2] => 19
    [5] => 18
    [8] => 15
    [12] => 14
    [15] => 13
    [18] => 11
    [23] => 9
)
```